# Intellij SBT project: How to change the content roots?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-scala

This is the current content root configuration in my project:

[image: current configuration]

However, I want the "scala" directory to be the actual test content root, and not the directory named "test". If I modify it, I get the warning that *"Module is imported from Sbt. Any changes in its configuration will may be lost after re-importing."* (and, indeed, they are).

[image]

Unfortunately, I couldn't find where in my Build.scala file (or any other file) this configuration is declared. What I can do to once and for all convince IntelliJ that "scala" is the correct test content root?

This is my Build.scala file (this is a Play 2.5.4 project if it matters):

```
import play.routes.compiler.StaticRoutesGenerator
import play.sbt.PlayScala
import play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys._
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object Build extends Build {
  val main = Project("Mp3Streamer", file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      // a bunch of dependencies
    ),

    resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal,
    javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xmx4000M", "-Xms2024M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2000M"),
    routesGenerator := StaticRoutesGenerator
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test" "/scala",` to my Build.scala file, I've been able to make the "scala" folder a test source, but the parent "test" folder was still also a test source:

[image]

As far as I could tell, this is a setting inherited from Play, since if I removed the `.enablePlugins(PlayScala)` code, the "test" folder stops being a test source. Following the instructions in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anatomy#Default-SBT-layout, I disabled the play layout, and then manually added the source and resource directories, which I copied from https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlayLayoutPlugin.scala#L9, only modifying the test source, and adding my own resource folders. My modified Build.scala file is now:

```
val main = Project("Mp3Streamer", file("."))
      .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
      .disablePlugins(PlayLayoutPlugin)
      .settings(
           target := baseDirectory.value / "target",

           sourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "app",
           // My change
           sourceDirectory in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test" / "scala",

           resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "conf",

           scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "app",
           // My change
           scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test" / "scala",
           // I've added this resource
           resourceDirectory in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test" / "resources",

           javaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "app",

           sourceDirectories in(Compile, TwirlKeys.compileTemplates) := Seq((sourceDirectory in Compile).value),
           sourceDirectories in(Test, TwirlKeys.compileTemplates) := Seq((sourceDirectory in Test).value),

           // sbt-web
           sourceDirectory in Assets := (sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "assets",
           sourceDirectory in TestAssets := (sourceDirectory in Test).value / "assets",


           resourceDirectory in Assets := baseDirectory.value / "public",

           // Native packager
           sourceDirectory in Universal := baseDirectory.value / "dist",

           // Everything else is the same as the original Build.scala file
```

Honestly, this feels so hacky that I'll probably end up modifying my directory structure to match Play's default... But it's the principle that counts!